# Перенаправление изображение с одного регистра на другой в .htaccess

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, site

столкнулись с такой проблемой. потребовалось восстановить изображения на сайте но вышла маленькая неувязачка. в архиве у нас все изображения в верхнем регистре .JPG на сайе же ссылки сохранились в нижнем .jpg

Менять регистр не вариант так как изображение больше пары тысяч.  Пробовали сделать перенаправление но не очень то и получилось. Перенаправление надо не везде а лишь в конкретных папках. Или хотябы подскажите может по другому можно реализовать?

```
RewriteRule ^wp-content/uploads/2020/02/(.*jpg)$ wp-content/uploads/2020/02/(.*JPG) [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `Менять регистр не вариант так как изображение больше пары тысяч`, почему? Написать простенький скрипт не проблема же.

Comment: эх если бы умели такое делать то бы сделали. но увы....

Comment: Жаль я не с пк.. накидал бы, если до завтра не предложат ничего, сделаю днем.

Comment: был бы очень благодарен.

Comment: Есть успехи? Если нет, что-то для связи дайте.

Comment: Есть телега/вк?